# How to use Guard to manage a ruby file?

Tags: ruby, guard

I have a ruby file that runs indefinitely. It is started with `ruby file.rb`. It is stopped with CTRL-C.

How to use Guard to start, stop and restart it?

I am using guard-process, which starts the file correctly. However, when exiting guard, it raises this exception:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `kill' for Guard::Process:Class
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be fixed if you upgrade your version of `guard` (2.10.3 is latest) and `guard-process` (version 1.1.0 was recently released).

If not, submit an issue at: https://github.com/guard/guard-process along with the backtrace you're getting.